# Angular ui-router with url query parameter containing a "dot"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, urlencode, query-string

In our Angular app we have to deal with id's that contain a "dot". For example:

```
book = {
  id: '123.456'
}
```

We have problems using such id's as url parameters. All works well if navigation occurs through "Angular", namely clicking on the link that invokes `$state.go('bookDetails', {bookId: book.id});`. But things do not work when reloading the page

"Cannot GET /bookDetails?bookId=123.456"

in the controller:

```
$scope.viewBookDetails = function() {
    $state.go('bookDetails', {bookId: book.id});
}
```

in the view

```
<a href="" ng-click="viewBookDetails(); $event.stopPropagation();">
```

in the router:

```
.state('bookDetails', {
    url: '/bookDetails?bookId'
}
```

in the browser:

```
https://example.com/bookDetails?bookId=123.456
```

The link works if the "dot" is replaced with `%2E` in the browser.

We tried to replace "dot" with "%2E" in the parameter for $state.go()

```
$scope.viewBookDetails = function() {
    $state.go('bookDetails', {bookId: book.id.split('.').join('%2E')});
}
```

but does not work because the "%" is automatically encoded and the "dot" in the browser is replaced by "%252E"

```
https://example.com/bookDetails?bookId=123%252E456
```

Comment: Maybe use sluggify for this: https://github.com/paulsmith/angular-slugify I am not sure if it works in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The refresh problem I was getting with a url query parameter containing a 'dot' is a server problem.
It is caused by the way I deal with html5mode (redirect to index.html if is not a static resource) in the grunt server settings

```
// The original grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          require('connect-modrewrite')(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']), //Matches everything that does not contain a '.' (period) and causes the problem
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

I changed

```
require('connect-modrewrite')(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
```

to

```
require('connect-modrewrite')([
  '!\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\.svg|\\.jp(e?)g|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.ttf$ /index.html'
]),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) on your server (like [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) does), the URLs with a dot are not rewritten by default.

[connect-history-api-fallback code](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/blob/e5bc77c5b1e3c9d07647764675971d262e773ac9/lib/index.js#L59-l67)

```
if (parsedUrl.pathname.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
  logger(
    'Not rewriting',
    req.method,
    req.url,
    'because the path includes a dot (.) character.'
  );
  return next();
}
```

Starting with `connect-history-api-fallback` version **1.2.0** the [URLs with dots are allowed](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/commit/7dbc0bddd37eaa21fa71f4167939f59dc14367c9) and you can solve [this problem](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/issues/5) by using a a [rewrite roule](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#rewrites)

**Example**

If your URL with dot is `/api/test/:id` (ex. `/api/test/123.34` ) and you angular app lives in the `index.html` page you can add a rewrite rule to the connect-history-api-fallback like this

```
rewrites: [
  {
    from: /^\/api\/test\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/,
    to: 'index.html'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I completely revised the code. I can use dots fine so please fork the plunker to show where you are getting an error.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ct09Q9uoc282JuWdsO1s?p=preview

```js
console.log("Scripts loading... ");

// Here's a skeleton app.  Fork this plunk, or create your own from scratch.
var app = angular.module('demonstrateissue', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $state){
  $scope.book = {
  id: '123.456'
};
  
  $scope.viewBookDetails = function() {
    console.log('new id');
    $state.go('bookDetails', {bookId: 456.3456});
  }
});



// Empty config block.  Define your example states here.
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('bookDetails', {
    url: '/bookDetails:bookId',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) { 
      $scope.book = {
       id: $stateParams.bookId
      };
    },
    template: "<h3>book: {{book}}</h3>"
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/bookDetails/91.23");
});

// Adds state change hooks; logs to console.
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location) {
  
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$location = $location;
  
  function message(to, toP, from, fromP) { 
    return from.name  + angular.toJson(fromP) + " -> " + to.name + angular.toJson(toP);
  }
  
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",   function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP)      { console.log("Start:   " + message(to, toP, from, fromP)); });
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP)      { console.log("Success: " + message(to, toP, from, fromP)); });
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError",   function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP, err) { console.log("Error:   " + message(to, toP, from, fromP), err); });
});
```

```css
body { 
  margin-top: 6em;
}
.link { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}

.link:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header { 
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 6em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Plunk demonstrating ui-router issue</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="demonstrateissue">

      <div ui-view>ui-view not populated</div>  
    
      <div class="header">
        Current URL: <b>{{$location.url() }}</b> <br>
        Current State: <b>{{$state.current.name }}</b> <br>
        Current Params: <b>{{$state.params | json }}</b><br>
      </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{book}}
      <br/>
      <a ui-sref="bookDetails({bookId: 6789.1011})">Change params to book with dot</a><br/>
      <button ng-click="viewBookDetails()">View Book Details</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how would you use this in $stateProvider.state() ?

Comment: I updated the code please review and let me know where your error.

Comment: As I already said, the problem is not going to the state but when **reloading** the bookDetails page (browser refresh when on the bookDetails).

Comment: I put my demo app in Webstorm ran it. Then tried links and clicked refresh and everything works fine. I can change my params and it works fine. Please review your code compared to mine. If you STILL are having issues Paste your code in a plunker so users can help you debug a working example instead of just slices you copied and pasted.

Comment: interesting, I am using html5mode, could that be a difference?

Comment: the problem with the refresh is a server problem, I am using the connect server started by `grunt serve` of the yeoman angular generator. I guess the origin of the problem is in there...

Comment: yes the problem is in the grunt server settings to deal with html5mode. I changed it and now things work. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: If you are using connect-history-api-fallback (like lite-server does) have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542479/dot-in-query-string-parameter-angularjs/36283859#36283859